# Cancel the execution of Camunda timer events after they fire

Tags: java, camunda

I want to decide programatically, for all the timer events on every process, if I really want them to start an event or not, after they fire.

I registered a listener for the start event which is being called and I try to terminate the `ActivityExecution` but It's not working.

My listener looks like this:

```
public class StartEventDelegate implements DelegateListener<ActivityExecution> {
private ProcessEngineServices processEngine;

public CamundaStartEventDelegate(ProcessEngineServices processEngine) {
    this.processEngine = processEngine;
}

@Override
public void notify(ActivityExecution instance) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("StartEvent triggered, eventName={}...", instance.getEventName());

    if (abortThisExecution(instance)) {
        LOG.info("Terminating instance");
        instance.end(true);
    }
}
```

When I run it, It appears that after I call the `instance.end(true)` the listener is invoked again but on the 2nd time the call to `instance.end(true)` fails.

```
2017-06-23T17:33:18,340 [DEBUG] pool-3-thread-1 [CamundaStartEventDelegate notify:50] StartEvent triggered, eventName=start...
2017-06-23T17:33:18,355 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 [CamundaStartEventDelegate notify:77] Terminating instance
2017-06-23T17:33:18,362 [DEBUG] pool-3-thread-1 [CamundaStartEventDelegate notify:50] StartEvent triggered, eventName=start...
2017-06-23T17:33:18,364 [INFO ] pool-3-thread-1 [CamundaStartEventDelegate notify:77] Terminating instance
2017-06-23T17:33:18,364 [ERROR] pool-3-thread-1 [context logError:156] ENGINE-16006 BPMN Stack Trace:
        StartEvent_1i6cslv (activity-end, ProcessInstance[13])
        StartEvent_1i6cslv

2017-06-23T17:33:18,365 [ERROR] pool-3-thread-1 [context logError:156] ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.getFlowScopeExecution(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1448) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.createActivityExecutionMapping(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1438) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.java:53) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.execute(PvmAtomicOperationActivityEnd.java:32) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:611) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:587) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd$1.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:44) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd$1.callback(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:38) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.continueExecutionIfNotCanceled(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1942) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.dispatchDelayedEventsAndPerformOperation(PvmExecutionImpl.java:1891) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:38) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(PvmAtomicOperationActivityNotifyListenerEnd.java:24) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:65) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:611) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:587) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.end(PvmExecutionImpl.java:334) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at my.company.workflow.camunda.delegate.CamundaStartEventDelegate.notify(CamundaStartEventDelegate.java:78) ~[main/:?]
        at my.company.workflow.camunda.delegate.CamundaStartEventDelegate.notify(CamundaStartEventDelegate.java:36) ~[main/:?]
        at my.company.workflow.StartEventDelegate.notify(StartEventDelegate.java:31) ~[main/:?]
        at my.company.workflow.StartEventDelegate.notify(StartEventDelegate.java:20) ~[main/:?]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.instance.CoreExecution.invokeListener(CoreExecution.java:95) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:52) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:622) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:597) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:622) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:597) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:622) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:597) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:622) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:597) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:69) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:622) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:597) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.core.operation.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:58) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:611) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:587) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationActivityStartCreateScope.scopeCreated(PvmAtomicOperationActivityStartCreateScope.java:39) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:50) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.operation.PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.execute(PvmAtomicOperationCreateScope.java:24) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.AtomicOperationInvocation.execute(AtomicOperationInvocation.java:89) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.invokeNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:125) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performNext(CommandInvocationContext.java:112) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvocationContext.performOperation(CommandInvocationContext.java:79) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:611) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:587) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.PvmExecutionImpl.start(PvmExecutionImpl.java:231) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.start(ExecutionEntity.java:432) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:55) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceCmd.java:31) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:104) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:66) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.executeWithVariablesInReturn(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:156) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.execute(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:122) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.execute(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:118) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.TimerStartEventJobHandler.startProcessInstance(TimerStartEventJobHandler.java:54) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.TimerStartEventJobHandler.execute(TimerStartEventJobHandler.java:43) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.TimerStartEventJobHandler.execute(TimerStartEventJobHandler.java:24) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.execute(JobEntity.java:129) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.ExecuteJobsCmd.execute(ExecuteJobsCmd.java:99) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.ExecuteJobsCmd.execute(ExecuteJobsCmd.java:36) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24) ~[camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:104) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:66) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobHelper.executeJob(ExecuteJobHelper.java:35) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobHelper.executeJob(ExecuteJobHelper.java:28) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.executeJob(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:82) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.jobexecutor.ExecuteJobsRunnable.run(ExecuteJobsRunnable.java:56) [camunda-engine-7.6.0.jar:7.6.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you add executionlisteners to the end event of a timer?

Comment: @JanGalinski I know very little about Camunda. My implementation was what I could come up with. I'll try your suggestion and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Use no Camunda classes and interfaces in your code that have an `*.impl.*` in their full-qualified class name. Their are not public API. Unexpected things may happen, undocumented things will happen. If you then can't find a way to implement your use case (and someone more experienced cannot either), then Camunda does not support it.

Comment: @JanGalinski I was thinking about what you said and I realized I don't know what you mean. As far as I understand, timers are a type of start event and I can add a listener to that. I can also add listeners to the end events but I would only have one of those after the task I want to prevent from running and I don't understand how would that help me because by then everything would have ran already.

Comment: So the use case you want to support is: timer-start-event triggers process but when it finds out that no action is required, you immediately kill the instance again? I would just model this in the process, so have an exclusice gateway after process start and link to an end event if condition is not met. Messing with the processinstance lifecycle from within the same instance leads to really ugly symptoms.

Comment: Ideally I would like not to change the bpmn. Who designs the bpmn won't be aware of this because basically I will deploy the bpmn twice without the user knowing and then each instance will need to check if the other has already run and abort if it has. It would cause usability issues if the user had to be made aware of this.